# Crystal Reports problem

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm having problem in the following line:

```
rd.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperFanfoldStdGerman;
```

it throws an exception saying  HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

if I skip this line, the same error eccurs here:

```
rd.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(config)
```

Did anyone have this problem before?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your line before is failing and as such gets reported on the next call.
Check the line before

```
rd.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperFanfoldStdGerman;
```

Comment: hi, the line before is rd.SetDataSource(dsReport); but what would be wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

The problem was a field that did not exist in the DataSet.